# Object designer always prompt user/password window

Tags: navision, dynamics-nav-2016

When I run he object designer in nav 2016 always ask for username and password. Sometimes i loose to much time typing my credentials.. is there a way to avoid this and "remember"? If i check the "remember password" it prompts again

[image]

Comment: If you check "remember password", it will continue to prompt the dialog window, but pre-fill it with saved login and password, so that you only need to press OK.

Comment: Otherwise you can setup NAV server instance (and client) to use Windows authentication instead of (presumbaly) NavUserPassword. There are no other direct ways to get rid of the Login window.

Comment: The first approach don't result. If I check save password it prompt again. I can try to setup the nav with windows authentication maybe cam help